# Expected value of number of balls chosen until all the balls disappear

Tags: probability, expectation

There are 5 types of balls in a box. The quantity of each ball present is
$x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$ ($x_1$ balls of 1st type, $x_2$ balls of 2nd type etc.) Now if we choose any one of the balls of type 1, 2, 3 or 4 all the balls of **that** chosen type get destroyed in the box. However if we choose a ball of type 5, all the balls **(every type)** in the box get destroyed.

I need to find the expected value of number of balls chosen until the box gets empty (all balls destroyed).

Is there an easier way to find the answer somehow using the Linearity of Expectation?
Or do I need to find probability corresponding to each possible case?

Comment: Assuming $x_5>0$, then the chosen ball that empties the box is always a ball of type 5; so you're looking for the distribution of the first type-5 ball chosen. Letting $x=\sum_{j=1}^5 x_j$, the probability that the first type-5 ball is the $k$th ball chosen is exactly $$\frac1{x!} \prod_{j=0}^{k-2} (x-x_5-j) \cdot x_5 \cdot (x-k)!....$$

Comment: @GregMartin: You seem to be assuming $x!$ equiprobable orderings. But since all balls of a type are destroyed if only one of them is drawn, there's no drawing of $x$ balls that defines an ordering among them (even if you continue drawing after drawing a ball of type $5$).

Comment: @LTim: This question was asked several times within a short time period quite recently; I think it must have been a contest question at that point. I don't know how to find the duplicates, but I'm pretty sure the result was that there's no closed solution and you have to enumerate all the orders in which the ball types can get destroyed.